# Visual Studio 2012 Boost.Python Integration

Tags: c++, python, boost, visual-studio-2012

I am writing some Python scripts that gathers data from an application written i C++ to plot and visualize the data. The C++ application projects are bundled in a relatively large Visual Studio 2012 solution file, while the Python scripts until now has been written separately in some other editor (e.g. Notepad ++).

Moreover, the C++ source, which sends the data to the Python script, is compiled using the Boost.Python `bjam` command. This builds the required C++/Python libraries and creates a `.pyd` extension module containing the desired C++ objects which I want to import into the script. This is done using a `Jamroot.jam` file in the script directory.

I would like to integrate these Python scripts into my C++ solution. I have created a Python project within the solution already, but I don't know how to invoke the `bjam`command on the C++ file.

Is there any way to set the project properties in Visual Studio to invoke the `bjam`command and the `Jamroot.jam` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can invoke almost any command as a part of either a pre- or post-build step.  The difference is that if you use post-build you will only update at the end of a successful build.[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. So do I just type my desired commands into the Command Line field? Is there anything else I should be aware of? I'm kind of new to Visual Studio, so this help is much appreciated.

Comment: I would be tempted to put all the commands into a batch file or script file and just use that in the Command Line field - you also need to set up either execute before or execute after.  I think that your script should return 0 if successful and a -ve on fail.

Comment: OK! Doing so produces an error message `fatal error LNK1561: entry point must be defined`. I guess it complains about not having a `main`file. However, it shouldn't need one as the C++ file just contains a class definition and a Boost.Python module passing function. Any idea on what's wrong, or what I can do to fix this? I have set the Execute Before option to "Build", but I'm not sure if this is right.